# Enable USB debugging for Android at Android Linux command

Tags: linux, usb-debugging

OS: Android JB.

HW Platform 1: sama5d31-ek (ATMEL ARM)

HW Platform 2: TI-Sitara SK

Enable USB debugging for android at android Linux command prompt.

Usually USB debugging for android is enabled through Settings > Developer option > USB debugging.

How can the same thing be achieved on a Headless Android Application? Since there is no user input from the touch screen what is the process to switch on the same feature at Android Linux command prompt.

The following links give some suggestions as to how it can be done but was not able to successfully achieve the objective.

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1621602
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326806/enable-usb-debugging-through-clockworkmod-with-adb
- http://cphacker0901.wordpress.com/1900/12/02/manually-update-settings-in-command-line/

HW Platform 1: sama5D31-ek (Atmel ARM) board has two USB/Serial input from android Linux can be accessed. From one USB/Serial port the adb shell can be executed when the USB debugging is enabled. The access provides root privileges.

The other USB/Serial access point pretty much for debugging, and has very limited privileges.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. It may help us to know a bit more about your setup. Your title seems to indicate that you have a working shell on the Android device. Is this the case? What options *do* you have to interface with the device, since you don't have a touchscreen?

Comment: It might be possible to call some intent (via `am start`) to trigger that. But I don't know if such exists, and which it might be. You could try [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+"am+start+-a"+enable+"usb+debugging"&hl=en) for some hints.

Comment: Perhaps try `start adbd` in the console?

Comment: Try this link : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877951/usb-debugging-option-not-available

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just type:

```
setprop persist.service.adb.enable 1
```

This will enable USB debugging on the device and persist across reboots.

Comment: You should be rooted to do that..